# Laravel Socialite Login with Google - userFromToken

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement Laravel social login with google, But I am stuck with the given bug.

```
message: "Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:{  "error": "invalid_request",  "error_description": "Invalid Credentials"}"
```

And here is my Laravel code.

```
  public function Sociallogin($provider,Request $request)
  {

      $token = $request->input('token');
      $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($token);

      die($user);
  }
```

Please note this code is working in login with Facebook. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @RoseRiyadh Yes, I have found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Finally I have found the solution, The error occurred which was I have given the wrong credentials of the google developer account. If anybody occurred the same error please verify credentials.

Comment: thanks for information, I got the issue